# Cannot use let to define a variable with the same name of function's parameter

Tags: javascript

I am returning to javaScript after a long absence and I've just learnt about ES6 new features. And here it comes the first doubt.

Although I understand that a `let` variable cannot be declared twice in the same block scope I came across this situation:

```
    function tell(story){
       let story = {
          story
        };
     }
```

And it gives me a error:
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'story' has already been declared`

Using `var` this works just fine.

1) Does this mean that I will have to declare a variable with a different name of the function's parameter using `let` (or even `const`)? This can be very annoying in terms of variable naming.

In order to keep the same name I did:

```
function tell(story){
     story = {
        story
     };
}
```

2) In this case the variable `story` will belong exclusively to the scope of the function `tell`?

Comment: As expected, because then, when you reference `story` later in the `tell` function, how would the interpreter know which binding of `story` you're trying to refer to?

Comment: Do you understand what `let` does? Here, you're trying to declare a variable which has already been declared ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Using `var` this works just fine.

Not really, the `var` is completely ignored, and you'd effectively have:

```
function tell(story){
   story = {
      story
   };
 }
```

If that's what you want, just leave the `var` (and `let`) off entirely (as above).

The error from `let` addresses this pitfall, where you think you've created a (new) variable but haven't. You can't use `let` (or `const`) to declare a variable that's already declared in the same scope (either as a variable, or as a parameter, which is almost the same thing as a variable).

> 1) Does this mean that I will have to declare a variable with a different name of the function's parameter using `let` (or even `const`)? This can be very annoying in terms of variable naming.

That's up to you. To keep doing what you were doing, just leave off `var`, `let`, and `const` entirely, because again, the `var` had no effect at all and you were assigning to the parameter, not a new variable. Or keep doing what you were doing (with `var`), but understand that it's misleading. Or use a different name with `let` or `const` — there are many who believe changing the value of a parameter isn't best practice (personally I'm not one of them, but...) and they'd recommend a different variable instead.

> 2) In this case the variable `story` will belong exclusively to the scope of the function `tell`?

Yes, you're assigning to the parameter `story`, which is local to `tell`.

Answer (score 2):

> "the var is completely ignored"

Not really, consider the following two examples:
1:

```
function someFn(a, b = () => a) {
  console.log(a, b());

  a = 2;
  
  console.log(a, b());
}
someFn(3);
```

2:

```
function someFn(a, b = () => a) {
  console.log(a, b());

  var a = 2;
  
  console.log(a, b());
}
someFn(3);
```

In the first example the output will be:
`3 3` 
`2 2` 
And in the second one:
`3 3` 
`2 3` 
So `var` does matter.